# Analytic uniformization of CM elliptic curves.

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Let $E_{|F}$ be an elliptic curve  defined over the number field $F$ with complex multiplication by an order $\mathcal{O}$ in its CM field $K$. It seems to be well known that one can choose an embedding of $F$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $E(\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb{C}/\mathcal{O}$. Can anyone explain how this is done? A priori $E(\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Can we choose an embedding so that such $\Lambda$ is homothetic to $\mathcal{O}$? Thanks.

Comment: In general, you cannot do this; the best you can do is $E(\Bbb C)\cong \Bbb C/\mathcal I$ where $\mathcal I$ is an ideal of $\mathcal O$.

Comment: I can see that $E(\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb{C}/\mathcal{I}$ by scaling $\Lambda$ by an appropriate element of $K$. I am asking because I am reading the paper of Bourdon and Pollack "Torsion  subgroups of CM elliptic curves over odd degree number fields" where they mention it in the proof of proposition 2.2 on page 4930. If I am not mistaken, I also remember to have seen it mentioned in the book "Seminar on complex multiplication" by Borel, Serre et al. I will have to doublecheck though.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The question is, if I get it right, why are the $j$-invariants of $\mathbb C/I$'s, with $I\subset\mathcal O$ ideals in a fixed $\mathcal O$, conjugate (over $\mathbb Q$). [I am not competent to answer it, I would just mumble something about Hilbert class field]

Comment: Sorry, "embedding of $K$ in \mathbb{C}" should read "embedding of $F$ in \mathbb{C}". I have edited already. Thanks.

Comment: @user8268 The $j$-invariants of the $\mathbb{C}/\mathcal{I}$ corresponding to curves with CM by $\mathcal{O}$ are conjugate, they are exactly the roots of the Hilbert class polynomial $H_{\mathcal{O}}(X)$ associated to $\mathcal{O}$ which is of degree $# Pic_{\mathcal{O}}$. The question is if we can choose an embedding of $F$ such that over $\mathbb{C}$, after analytic uniformization, we get a curve isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/\mathcal{O}$. My apologies for the bad text output, I am relatively new here :).